# Rendering a dynamic list of labels from a List<String>

Tags: cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I need to do something similar to:

```
@Query("MATCH (n:`:#{literal(#label)}`) WHERE n.entityId=$entityId  RETURN n")
Mono<VisibilityGroup> findNode(UUID entityId, String label);
```

but specifying a list of labels in OR:

```
Mono<VisibilityGroup> findNode(UUID entityId, List<String> labels);
```

if label is {"A","B"} this should generate:

MATCH (n:A|B) WHERE...

What is the correct syntax to achieve this?

Comment: FYI: You inspired me to do this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/issues/2681

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now this would be only possible if you concatenate the `List<String>` to a `String` with `|` separator.

```
String labels = String.join("|", List.of("A", "B"));
```

or

```
String labels = new StringJoiner("|")
        .add("A")
        .add("B")
        .toString();
```

The `literal` function will create a `[A,B]` value which is incompatible to the expected pattern in the pattern (obviously).
In the longer run it might make sense to evaluate if it's possible to integrate a more specialised keyword (like `#{labels(..)}`) in Spring Expression Language containing queries for Spring Data Neo4j.